# After power outage, no power at 3 bedrooms and bathroom, which are all on the same circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 3 bedrooms and a bathroom on one circuit, after a power outage and power restored, the 3 bedrooms and bath have no power, except that the gfci in the bath does have power.

The circuit breaker didn't trip, and I checked the wires at the breaker with a ncvt voltage tester, and they have voltage. The breaker functions properly when I cycle it off and on, corresponding with the voltage tester.

I traced the wires partially from the breaker up through the attic in the garage with v. tester.

I am about to go up into the crawl space above the bedrooms, but I'm looking for a shortcut. How do I figure out which room is first to get power?

any ideas?

Comment: A good guess is the room closest to the panel.  People like to save money and don't like to use extra copper to go to the farthest room first, then back.  Check outlets for being connected by back stabs instead of by screws.  Change back stabs to the screws and your problem might disappear.

Comment: Confusing, the GFCI has power, did you reset it

Comment: I didn't need to reset the gfci, but I  did anyway, the receptacle has power.

Comment: I traced the wires into my daughter's br, I'll check the recepticles, I opened the light switch, no power.

Comment: Good news, the first recepticle had power, but the wires are fried, and yes it has back stabs.   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When laying out a circuit you are trained to start at the device or fixture farthest away from the panel and work your way to the panel. That would mean that the closest device or fixture to the panel would be the first in line in the circuit. Obviously this is not necessarily true, but it does establish a pattern.

I don't really think that is your problem. If you are using a non-contact power sensor. It will show that there is power at any given location, but it will not show that there is a complete circuit. You could have line current at each location but not have a complete neutral or return. Meaning your problem may be a loose or disconnected neutral.

If you want to check that you are going to need a voltmeter and check each opening for voltage between the line conductor and the neutral to see if you are getting proper voltage. Just start out the Panel and work your way to the end.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: It might where you are, but in UK we have ring mains, where the first and last on a circuit join back at the panel. We can only guess where Erik is living, and like I've said many times, questions such as this could benefit with a location.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very glad you found the first outlet and its back stabs, but I'm also quite concerned. Back Stabs are absolutely terrible and should've never been approved by the idiot electricians.

Please take this opportunity and either completely replace those outlets or use their screw-on connections at a minimum. Getting off easy this time is possibly a very false peace of mind.